# Disabling QGraphicsWebView scrollbars

Tags: c++, qt, mobile, scrollbars

I want to disable the scrollbars in a `QGraphicsWebView`. It says in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicswebview.html):

> "... if the Web page contents is larger than that, scrollbars will be shown if not disabled explicitly."

I can't seem to find a way to disable the scrollbars.
I need to disable the scrollbars because I want to implement scrolling on drag and I don't want them to be shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the scrollbar behaviour on QWebFrame.  What you probably want is something like:

```
QWebFrame* frame = webView->page()->mainFrame();
frame->setScrollBarPolicy( Qt::Horizontal, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff );
frame->setScrollBarPolicy( Qt::Vertical, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff );
```

Answer (score 1):

The page itself needs to have appropriate CSS to prevent the scrollbars from appearing, e.g. `body {overflow: hidden}`.

If you don't have control over the page contents, [resizesToContents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicswebview.html#resizesToContents-prop) might be the property you're looking for.